# SqlDataReader for 2 reads of the same data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to read a value of a `data row` using 2 methods `GetSqlBinary` and `GetValue`

```
object o = null;
SqlBytes bytes = null;
try
{

     bytes = ((SqlDataReader)(dr)).GetSqlBytes(iCol); //1   o = dr.GetValue(iCol);
     o = dr.GetValue(iCol);                           //2   bytes = ((SqlDataReader)(dr)).GetSqlBytes(iCol);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("exception");
}
```

It always throws an exception even after I changed line#1 into #2.
That means, during debug I see a valid value a line#1 but then an exception is thrown at line#2.

I think `GetValue` returns `object` as its type while `SqlBytes` or `SqlBinary` is also derives from `object`. Why do I have an exception? and how can I get the value of both type of the same database cell?

Comment: Throws *what*? A NullReferenceException has nothing to do with casting for example. BTW why is `o` defined as an object? Unless you intend to use it to store different types of values (a very bad idea) it should be strongly typed and defined *inside* the `try` block. Preferably, in the same line it's assigned, ie `var bytes=dr.GetSqlBytes(iCol);`. Using `object` or giving variables greater scope than necessary can easily lead to bugs

Comment: What exception do you get? Just because they derive from object does not mean you can change them to `SqlBytes` or whatever. It means you can always change them to `object`.

Comment: Instead of hiding the exception with `catch`, catch it and log it. Otherwise you'll have no idea what went wrong. At the very least use `catch(Exception ex){ MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());}`

Comment: What is the type of the column in the database? Are you sure you're using the correct column index (e.g. try running `dr.GetFieldType(iCol)`)? Why are you trying to read the same field twice (note that `GetSqlBytes` returns a stream over the data, while `GetValue` would just return a `byte[]` for a binary field)?

Comment: You're assuming that you can get the value from the reader twice, but that's not necessarily the case. The data reader might be in forward-only mode. Buffering might be disabled for binary fields (especially if used for `SqlBytes`, which is meant for streaming large amounts of data). What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Luaan the type of the column is `Structured`. I want to get the value of that column in both `binary` and `object` type formats. And I think `binary` is of `object`. But sometimes the object returned becomes `null`, and the exception of "Invalid format".